# drupal ajax callback on language selection

Tags: php, drupal

Is there way to bind an ajax callback when the language is changed, i want to update a nodereference-dropdown when a language is changed (to show the values only in that language).

following code is not working (form_alter) although other callbacks are working.

Can someone help me how can i achieve that?

```
$form['language']['#ajax'] = array(
            'callback' => 'mymodule_something_language_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'my-module-replace',                
            '#weight' => 2
        );
```

Thanks.

**FROM COMMENTS**

heres the var_dump of $form['language'];

```
array
  '#type' => string 'select' (length=6)
  '#title' => string 'Language' (length=8)
  '#default_value' => string 'und' (length=3)
  '#options' => 
    array
      'und' => string 'Language neutral' (length=16)
      'en' => string 'English' (length=7)
      'ar' => string 'Arabic' (length=6)
```

Comment: not working means that ajax callback is not getting fired when i change the value in language dropdown but the exact same code works for other dropdown fields.

Comment: How do you know the AJAX callback isn't firing?

Comment: Definitely remove the `#weight` from the `#ajax` property, it doesn't belong there

Comment: @Clive i dont know if `#weight` makes a difference i copied it from a tutorial and this has worked very well for other dropdowns, i will remove that and check again

Comment: @jantimon no the ajax request is not getting sent in the network tab

Comment: You could try to set `['#ajax']['event'] = 'change'` but that shouldn't be necessary. Do you get any js errors?

Comment: Are you sure your form_alter is called and you are using `&$form`?

Comment: yes, my form alter is called, as i said other callbacks are working perfectly fine in the same form_alter, this one isnt and no i dont get any js errors

Comment: Same problem here, my ajax event isn't firing. I don't see any items in the network tab of chrome. Did you fix the problem meanwhile? I'm adding the ajax callback in this function: `hook_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`. If I check my `$form["language"]` it only contains `#type = "value"` and `#value = "und"`...

Comment: Strangely enough if I define my callback in the i18n_menu.module the $form["language"] is filled as a type select, and not only value and type. As reference I used this link: https://drupal.org/files/issues/restrict_parent_menu-5043252-4.patch if I define my ajax callback in that file it does get triggered, not in my custom module. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks to me like the language selection field gets build in a later process than my form_alter gets called. And overwrites the ajax i give with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Locale module alters this form element after hook_form_alter() is called (see [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47836/cannot-modify-language-field-in-node-form-using-hook-form-alter-in-drupal-7)).

Here's how I solved this problem:

First, change the order in which Drupal implements its hooks, putting 'form_alter' as the last one:

```
<?php 

/**
 * Implementation of hook_module_implements_alter()
 */
function chronos_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter') {
    // Move mymodule_form_alter() to the end of the list. module_implements()
    // iterates through $implementations with a foreach loop which PHP iterates
    // in the order that the items were added, so to move an item to the end of
    // the array, we remove it and then add it.
    $group = $implementations['chronos'];
    unset($implementations['chronos']);
    $implementations['chronos'] = $group;
  }
}
```

Next, add a form element and the '#ajax' element that you want on $form['language']:

```
<?php 

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'page_node_form') {
        // alter the form
        $form['container'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-language">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
        $form['language']['#ajax'] = array(
                'callback' => 'mymodule_save_language_callback',
                'wrapper' => 'ajax-language'
        );
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Lastly, add your callback:

```
<?php

/**
 * Returns changed part of the form.
 *
 * @return renderable array
 *
 * @see ajax_example_form_node_form_alter()
 */
function chronos_save_language_callback($form, $form_state) {
  # set session variables or perform other actions here, if applicable
  return $form['container'];
}
```